# An integral with residues

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am trying to calculate the following integral using the residual method
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}dx\frac{n \cos(x)(-a + 2r\cos(x))\sin(n(x+t))-(a-2)\cos(n(x+t))\sin(x)}{(a-2r\cos(x))^2} $$
where $n$ is a positive integer, $a$ is a positive real and $t \in(0,2\pi]$. The integral is done on the circle of radius 1.

Calling $z=e^{ix}$ I tried to calculate the pole contained in the circle $|z|=1$ and use the method of residuals. The poles are identified by the condition
$$ (a-r(z^{-1}+z) )^2=0  $$
and that contained in the unit circle is $z_0 = \frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4r^2}}{2r}$ with the condition $a > 2r$. How can I calculate the residue at this point?

Comment: Please post your code in Mathematica syntax ?. Nobody feels like retyping your code.

Comment: may be the [Residue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Residue.html) command could be of use here.

Comment: The integral written is not around the unit circle. So either what was written is incorrect, or the statement that this is a contour integral is incorrect.

Comment: Problem is confussing (1):  If integration is around circle then $x=re^{it}$, (2): The statement $t\in (0,2\pi)]$ conflicts with (1) above or else $t$ in integrand is a different $t$, (3):  Integrand has no poles if $a>2r$ so integral would be zero.

Comment: He seems to be using a somewhat non-standard naming convention for his variables. I.e. he defines z = Exp[I x], so x is an angular variable (normally theta/phi are used). This seems to be leading to some confusion. Also, t is some other phase angle (not time), so it's similar to theta0/phi0. The ''a' is defined as a positive real, but he didn't define 'r', but since he's using an inequality, it's presumably also a real of some kind. But josh is correct - since |cos[x]| <= 1, there's no pole if a>2r.

Comment: @jdp:  Ok thanks.  Still, I think  much clearer to write $$\displaystyle \mathop{\oint}_{z=e^{i\theta}} f(z;r,a,n,t)dz$$ .  In the case of poles can either use `Residue` command or simply compute expansion around poles using `Series` command and then Residue Theorem.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @Fred:  Afraid I made a mistake when I stated no poles when $a>2r$ by failing to consider complex values.  Apology for the distraction.   I'll post my results using both `Residue` and `Series` shortly unless someone does so before me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example computing integral 3 ways:  (1): Numerically, (2): Using the built-in `Residue` command, and (3): Using the built-in `Series` command:

```
a = 3;
r = 1;
n = 3;
t = Pi/4; 
theInt = (
  n Cos[x] (-a + 2 r Cos[x]) Sin[n (x + t)] - (a - 2) Cos[
     n (x + t)] Sin[x])/(a - 2 r Cos[x])^2;

poles = x /. Solve[(a - 2 r Cos[x]) == 0, x]
poles // N
```

The poles are in this case $\pm\arccos(3/2)+2k\pi,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pm \arccos(3/2)\approx \pm 0.962424i$ which are in the unit circle.

(1):   First numerically integrate it over the unit circle via $x=e^{i\theta}$:

```
NIntegrate[(theInt  I Exp[I theta]) /. x -> Exp[I theta], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]
(* 8.56637*10^-11 + 106.629 I *)
```

which gives approx $106.629i$ and a small residual real part.

(2): Use `Residue` to compute the residues at these poles and the Residue Theorem to compute the integral:

```
r1 = Residue[theInt, {x, -ArcCos[3/2]}] // N
r2 = Residue[theInt, {x, ArcCos[3/2]}] // N
2 Pi I (r1 + r2) // N
 (* 8.48528 - 8.53815 I
    8.48528 + 8.53815 I
    0. + 106.629 I *)
```

(3): Expand the integrand around each pole using `Series` and extract the $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x\pm \arccos(3/2)}$ terms as the residues:

```
series1 = Series[theInt, {x, ArcCos[3/2], 4}];
residue1 = Coefficient[series1, 1/(x - ArcCos[3/2])];
series2 = Series[theInt, {x, -ArcCos[3/2], 4}];
residue2 = Coefficient[series2, 1/(x + ArcCos[3/2])];
residue1 // N
residue2 // N

(*
Out[94]= 8.48528 + 8.53815 I
Out[95]= 8.48528 - 8.53815 I
(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

One has to use the transformation formula for residues over the sum of fractions with simple roots. But the pole is order 2, so there is no residue

```
    Residue[expr,{x,ArcCos[a/(2r)]}]
```

But for numeric integers, with a bit of preparing sums of integrands of simple exponentials in indefinite integrals, there are results

```
  Itg[m_, r_, a_] := 
   Itg[m] = 
   FullSimplify[
   Subtract @@ 
   (((Integrate[#, x] &) /@ 
     ExpandAll@
      TrigToExp@(
        (1/(a -2 r Cos[x])^2  * 
            (-2 a r Cos[x]^2 Sin[m ( t + x)] + 
            2 Cos[m ( t + x)] Sin[x] - 
            a Cos[m ( t + x)] Sin[x]) )) // 
    Simplify) /. {{x -> 2 \[Pi]}, {x -> 0}})]
```

Here are some

```
   {{0,n==0},
   {-((I a^2 E^(-I t) \[Pi])/r^2),n==1},
   {(I a E^(-2 I t) \[Pi] (4-2 a-3 a^2+2 r^2))/(2 r^3),n==2},
   {-((I E^(-3 I t) \[Pi] (a^2 (-6+a (3+4 a))-2 (-2+a+a^2) r^2))/(2 r^4)),n==3}}
```